# How to draw map using new Lat Lng in ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am passing proper latitude and longitude to the map but it shows old map, having old lat lng. I know I am doing something wrong in this, but I can't figure out it. My project in ionic framework and for map I am using this plugin [map plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps)

This my html code

```
        <div style="width:100%;height:200px" id="mapDisplay"></div>
```

This my angularJS code

```
var getLat = $scope.dealer.lat;
var getLng = $scope.dealer.lng;
var address = $scope.dealer.address;

var mapDiv = document.getElementById("mapDisplay");
const myGeoLocation = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(getLat,getLng);
var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(mapDiv, {
  'camera': {
    'latLng': myGeoLocation,
    'zoom': 15
  }
});

map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, function() {
  map.addMarker({
    'position': myGeoLocation,
    'title': address
  }, function(marker) {
    marker.showInfoWindow();
  });
});
```

Comment: i think that the lat lng are hardcoded somewhere. Try with real values for testing.

Comment: no i am passing dynamic values. I think that div not refresh

Comment: enter some known latlng here ......*const myGeoLocation = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(**getLat,getLng**);*

Comment: const myGeoLocation = new plugin.google.maps.L‌​atLng(-19.9178713, -43.9603117);

Comment: still having same issue?

Comment: yes, actually map draw at first time but after that its not refresh

Comment: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/10/implement-google-maps-using-ionicframework/

Comment: I am using this plugin https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Answer (score 0):

The plugin doesn't allow to create multiple maps instance [More detail](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Map.getMap()).

But you can achieve this by using this code

```
var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);
  map.clear();
  map.off();
  map.trigger("test");
  map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of the map plugin you are using

> This plugin generates only one map instance using the Map.getMap()
>   method. In general, you may want to create multiple maps, but this
>   plugin doesn't allow it.

So your `plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap` is only grabbing the existing instance, not creating a new one and the `plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY` is only fired once, the first time. However looking at the source code it looks like the instance exposes a [remove](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/blob/master/www/googlemaps-cdv-plugin.js#L730) method which you can use to destroy the existing instance and create a new one with the new sets of coordinates when the callback is called, e.g: `map.remove(function() { /** reset map coordinates **/ }`

** Extra **

If you just need to display a map with a set of coordinates you can do it using the native app by passing lat/lon to the [$cordovaInAppBrowser](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/) plugin. As an example for iOS and Android you'd have the following:

**iOS**

```
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open('maps://?q=<latitude>,<longitude>', '_system');
```

**Android**

```
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open('geo:0,0?q=<latitude>,<longitude>', '_system');
```

And finally you need to enable the geo uri in your config.xml like so:

```
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

Comment: Mark the question if it was of any help to you :)